# Phaser and issues with bounding box resizing on the fly

Tags: phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser and have an issue with resizing the Hitbox of a sprite in particular with collisions. This is a slightly contrived example to highlight the issue that I am having, rather than being best practice etc.

As you can see in the below example I have 2 sprites, 1 character and 1 enemy which both have bounding box's (shown with the debug.spriteBounds (the green tinge)).

[image]

When I attack I change the sprite of the player to a larger one in particular one with him slashing with a sword for a short period of time.

[image]

As you can see when the sprite is changed the bounding box is also resized, so all that is left is for me to check that a collision has occured which is the part that I run into issues.

Here is my code snippet

```
if (this.attackRight.justDown) {
                console.log('attacking');
                console.log('boundsBeforeAttack=', this.player._bounds);

                this.player.loadTexture('playerAttack', 0);

                this.g.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 0.5, function () {
                    console.log('boundsduringattack=', this.player._bounds);
                    console.log('touchingright=', this.player.body.touching.right);
                }, this);


                this.g.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 3.25, function () {
                    this.player.loadTexture('player', 0);
                }, this);
            }
```

Here is the following output:

```
attacking
_player.js:95 boundsBeforeAttack= c.Rectangle {x: 856.0833333333328, y: 737.0416666666679, width: 32, height: 32, offset: function…}
_player.js:100 boundsduringattack= c.Rectangle {x: 828.3333333333328, y: 737.6944444444443, width: 87.5, height: 32, offset: function…}
_player.js:101 touchingright= false
```

As you can see the bounds get larger, however this doesn't appear to be respected. I want touching right to become true.

Other things I have tried player.body.reset(); doesn't appear to do anything, using the physics.arcade.collide and overlay methods which also do the same thing.

Comment: I have also tried doing the collision detection like this - which has the exact same effect. 

this.g.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.g.enemy.sprite, function () {
                console.log('hit!');
            });

The reason I am currently using touching is because I need to know which side the attack is happening from which touch seems to be more appropriate for.

Comment: Not sure if it's going to work, but have you tried with overlap? http://phaser.io/docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#overlap

Answer (score 1):

`body.touching` is updated by calling `arcade.collide` or `arcade.overlap` first. See http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/one-way-collision for the basics (ignore the 1-way part).

Give your sprites physics bodies and use `debug.body` (instead of `debug.spriteBounds`).